# Shell script which finds the sum average and product of five numbers

Tags: ubuntu, scripting

This is what I have so far:

```
echo "Please enter your first number: "
read a
echo "Second number: "
read b
```

(etc..)
That works fine, but when I tried to set a function for sum average and product, I ran into some problems.

This is what I tried:

```
sum= ($a + $b + $c + $d + $e)
avg= ($sum / 5) #The five was showing up in red text
prod= ($a * $b * $c * $d * $e)

echo "The sum of these numbers is: " $sum
echo "The average of these numbers is: " $avg
echo "The product of these numbers is: " $prod
```

but when I ran it (after I inputted the numbers 1,2,3,4,5) I got this back:

```
The sum of these numbers is: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
The average of these numbers is:  1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 / 5
The product of these numbers is: 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5
```

So my question is how do I get these functions to compute within the ()

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please enter your first number: "
read a
echo "Second number: "
read b
echo "Third number: "
read c
echo "Fourth number: "
read d
echo "Fifth number: "
read e

sum=$(($a + $b + $c + $d + $e))
avg=$(echo $sum / 5 | bc -l ) 
prod=$(($a * $b * $c * $d * $e))

echo "The sum of these numbers is: " $sum
echo "The average of these numbers is: " $avg
echo "The product of these numbers is: " $prod
```

The only issue is some minor syntax troubles in the `sum`,`avg`,`prod` part.

The average is not done the way the other calculations are because it may return a floating-point number. This number is piped to `bc` and stored in `avg`.

---

When I run this program, I get the results:

```
Please enter your first number: 
2
Second number: 
2
Third number: 
2
Fourth number: 
3
Fifth number: 
2
The sum of these numbers is:  11
The average of these numbers is:  2.20000000000000000000
The product of these numbers is:  48
```

Comment: Great! Make sure to click the checkmark on this answer if it works for you, so this question can be marked as answered.

Comment: Sum and product worked but I got a syntax error in expression for the average. After that I tried this and got it to work.                                                                   avg=$(($sum / 5))

Answer (score 1):

```
read N
i=1
sum=0
while [ $i -le $N ]
do
  read num          
  sum=$((sum + num))     
  i=$((i + 1))
done
avg1=$(echo $sum / $N | bc -l);
echo "scale = 3; $avg1 / 1" | bc -l
```

This Code worked for me. Thanks to -oogy. for this part

> echo "scale = 3; $avg1 / 1" | bc -l`

Answer (score 0):

```
num1=$(( ( $RANDOM%6 ) + 1 ));
num2=$(( ( $RANDOM%6 ) + 1 ));
num3=$(( ( $RANDOM%6 ) + 1 ));
num4=$(( ( $RANDOM%6 ) + 1 ));
num5=$(( ( $RANDOM%6 ) + 1 ));
sum=$(( num1+num2+num3+num4+num5 ))
average=$(( sum/2 ))
echo "the sum is: " $sum
echo "the average: " $average
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).